# Adding minutes to given time Rstudio

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataframe where time is given in the format: Tue Apr 03 18:00:06 +0000 2012

And timezone offset is given in minutes in the format: 240

How do I add 240 minutes to the time above so I can get local time from UTC time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could convert to `POSIXct` and then add the `minutes`

```
library(lubridate)
out <- as.POSIXct(str1, format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y') %m+% minutes(240)
tz(out) <- "UTC"
out
#[1] "2012-04-03 22:00:06 UTC"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'Tue Apr 03 18:00:06 +0000 2012'
```